# Js : Chaining promises chains in a clear and readable way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Hello there overflowers,

I'm currently working on a project of mine, using a node server with a mongo data store. I'm currently writing some functions to populate the database for me.
Examples of objects in the database are Users,Classes,School Years,Students ratings, etc.
All the functions to create such objects are implemented like this :

```
    function popUser(users){
        chain = [];
        users.forEach((v,i,a)=>{
            let p = new Promise(function(res,rej){
                let newU = new User(v);
                newU.save(()=>{
                    err && rej(err);
                    res();
                });
            });
            chain.push(p);
        });
        return chain
    }
```

In the remainder of my population module i invoke such functions depending on my needs. The order in which the above functions are called is important, thus I don't want fully parallel execution of constructors.

With Promises I could do something like this :

```
popUser(users).then(popClasses).then(...). ... .catch((err)=>{})
```

With Promises Chains I know that I can do the following

```
Promise.all(usersChain).then(()=>{
    //make a new chain for Classes
    Promise.all(classesChain).then (()=>{},(err)=>{})
},(err)=>{})
```

I think we can agree that it becomes quite hard to read and understand, thus the question :

Is there a way of achieving the same results with a different, more readable syntax?

Edit : to be clearer, usersChain and cleassesChains are arrays of Promises to create and insert some object (or objects) into the database.
I can not make a single chain because some objects might have to be inserted after some other objects have already been inserted.

Edit : Wait, can I just call

```
Promsie.all(populateCountersPromise).then(promise1).then(promise2).catch((err)=>{})
```

Comment: Not sure what `usersChain`, or `classesChain` are..? (unless `classesChain` depends on `usersChain`, better to use a single `Promise.all`) Also note that your function name is `popUser` but you're invoking `popUsers`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've edited the code and added an edit section!

Comment: This is Mongoose, isn't it? The question should state this explicitly instead of 'Mongo'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different parts in the code that won't work, or should not be written that way.

If you use shortcuts like this:

```
err && rej(err);
res();
```

You should know what they mean, because this is equal to:

```
if( err ) { 
  rej(err);
}
res();
```

So if an error occurs both `rej` and `res` are called.

From your `popUser` you return an array of Promises, so `popUser(users).then(popClasses)` would fail, because you cannot call `.then` on an array.

The first thing you should do, is to clean up your `popUser` function:

```
function popUser(users) {

  let promises = users.map((v, i, a) => {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      let newU = new User(v);
      newU.save(err => {
        if (err) {
          rej(err)
        } else {
          res()
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return Promies.all(promises)
}
```

Use `.map` instead a `forEach` with a `push`, because it makes it clear right from the beginning what you do. And use `Promies.all` to return a Promise from your function that waits for all users to be saved, if you do the same for `popClasses` you can write it like:

```
popUser(users)
   .then(popClasses)
   .then(...)
   .catch((err)=>{})
```

If you really want to write it like in your last code snippet, then change it to this:

```
Promise.all(usersChain)
  .then(() => Promise.all(classesChain))
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(err => {})
```

Many APIs now adays support both the classical callbacks and Promises, so you could improve your `popUser` further:

```
function popUser(users) {
  let promises = users.map(v => new User(v).save())
  return Promies.all(promises)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!Never thought I could return .all and treat it as a promise, it's fantastic! I'm not sure about the first point tho, a call to reject would make it so that resolve is never called.

Comment: @FilippoBosco  `err && rej(err);` does not magically stop the execution of the code at `rej(err)` so `res()` will still be called. Calling `res` would not overwrite the rejection sate, but it is still a bad habit to do so. It will have an unwanted side effect if you e.g. do so something like `res(new Something())`, because then `new Something()` will be called even if you do a rejection.

Comment: Yea, makes sense I'll be more careful and thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose callbacks are legacy API. Mongoose supports promises for a long time and doesn't need to be promisified.

For concurrent promises, `forEach` can be replaced with `map`, this is exact use case for the latter:

```
function popUser(users){
  return Promise.all(
    users.map(userData => new User(userData).save())
  );
}
```

`async..await` can be used in the rest of the cases where promises should be sequential:

```
try {
  await popUser(users);
  await popClasses();
  ...
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not return `Promise.all(chain)` in function `popUser`.

Returning a Promise is better to match semantic of `popUser` which is a function of doing something asynchronously.Returning array of promise is confusing.

Then you can use `popUsers.then(popClasses).then(...). ... .catch((err)=>{})` to queue up promises